# How to return the reassigned function to its original state in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB we can assign a function name as a variable name, what is the command in MATLAB to reverse that variable name to the function name?

Answer (score 3):

remove the variable from memory with the clear function:

```
clear <variableName>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to clear the variable or use a different name for it, you can still access the function with [`feval`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html); or with [`builtin`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) if it's a built-in function:

```
>> find = 5; %// this variable definition shadows `find` function

>> find(([0 1 2]))
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. 

>> feval('find',[0 1 2])
ans =
     2     3
>> builtin('find',[0 1 2])
ans =
     2     3
```